# GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>() Getting error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have hub service and client. They are both talking but through console application, not able to inject `IHubContext`.

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubSec>("TestHub");
```

And I tried

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("TestHub");
```

Both time getting same error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'   That's the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the nuget `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` solved the issue for me.

Comment: This worked also for me, seems that GlobalHost.ConnectionManager. uses some performance counters. But in my case is unable to resolve the Hub. ''ThreadHub' Hub could not be resolved.' which i have in the Program.cs: 
app.MapHub<ThreadHub>("/threadhub");